# No session bound to the current context when redirecting to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, nhibernate

I have encounter a strange problem. I've set up and MVC 4 app uisng NHibernate followed by instructions in `ASP.NET MVC4 and the Web API published by apress`.

I manage session for actions using controller attribute named `[LoggingNhibernateSessionAttribute]`. It works well and I can do CRUD operations with NHibernate.

But problem arise when I add an `authorize` attribute to HomeController which redirects to login page. at the moment an exception occurs indicating

> "No session bound to the current context"

I looked a lot at my code. but I couldn't understand why session doesn't bound to current context.

```
public class LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IActionLogHelper _actionLogHelper;
    private readonly IActionExceptionHandler _actionExceptionHandler;
    private readonly IActionTransactionHelper _actionTransactionHelper;

    public LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute()
        : this(WebContainerManager.Get<IActionLogHelper>(),
        WebContainerManager.Get<IActionExceptionHandler>(),
        WebContainerManager.Get<IActionTransactionHelper>())
    {
    }

    public LoggingNHibernateSessionAttribute(
        IActionLogHelper actionLogHelper,
        IActionExceptionHandler actionExceptionHandler,
        IActionTransactionHelper actionTransactionHelper)
    {
        _actionLogHelper = actionLogHelper;
        _actionExceptionHandler = actionExceptionHandler;
        _actionTransactionHelper = actionTransactionHelper;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExectingContext)
    {
        _actionLogHelper.LogEntry(actionExectingContext.ActionDescriptor);
        _actionTransactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        _actionTransactionHelper.EndTransaction(actionExecutedContext);
        _actionTransactionHelper.CloseSession();
        _actionExceptionHandler.HandleException(actionExecutedContext);
        _actionLogHelper.LogExit(actionExecutedContext.ActionDescriptor);
    }
}
```

**ActionTransactionHelper**

```
public ActionTransactionHelper(
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory,
        ICurrentSessionContextAdapter currentSessionContextAdapter)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        _currentSessionContextAdapter = currentSessionContextAdapter;
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }
```

and here how I bind session to current sessionContext:

```
private ISession CreateSession(IContext context)
    {
        var sessionFactory = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>();
        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
        {
            // Open new ISession and bind it to the current session context
            var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
        }
        return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    }
```

does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What's the stack track for the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is related to the execution order of `IFilter` Attributes, described here: [Understanding Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) *(cite below)*

> The ASP.NET MVC framework supports four different types of filters:
>
> 1. Authorization filters – Implements the IAuthorizationFilter attribute.
> 2. Action filters – Implements the IActionFilter attribute.
> 3. Result filters – Implements the IResultFilter attribute.
> 4. Exception filters – Implements the IExceptionFilter attribute.
>
> **Filters are executed in the order listed above**. For example, authorization filters are always executed before action filters and exception filters are always executed after every other type of filter.

So, what we exeperience is:

- in the Action filter (second one) we do start NHibernate session
- in the Authorization filter (the very first one), we expect session to be in place

One solution is to start session in the `OnAuthorize` event...

Comment: thanks for your answer I didn't know about it. in somecontrollers I use Authorize atribute. so the better solution is putting session on the current context in onAuthorize event and ActionTransactionHelper class beginTransaction() method.

Comment: Yes, I do it this way, to be sure that the NH Session is ready for us anywhere...

Comment: would you check my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738907/nhibernate-session-is-closed-when-refereshing-page

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

```
public class AuthorizaAttributeWithSession : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public AuthorizaAttributeWithSession () : this(WebContainerManager.Get<ISessionFactory>())
    {
    }

    public AuthorizaAttributeWithSession(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.BeginTransaction();
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and my AdiminstratorAuthorize Filter:

```
public class AdministratorAuthorized : AuthorizaAttributeWithSession
{
    public AdministratorAuthorized()
    {
        Roles = "Administrators";
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you haven't to implement the same exception filter that will close a session? For the chance of exception in authorize attribute